# Find or assign a clientID to a HyperLinkColumn?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

We're using the ASP.Net DataGrid class which has a HyperlinkColumn, among other BoundColumns.

When the DataGrid renders on the screen it has an ID value (as assigned in the control on the aspx page) but the inner resulting  and  values have no ids associated with them.

Is it possible to assign or get ids for the resulting table entries resulting from a DataGrid?  We looked at adding an "ID" value to the HyperLinkColumn but apparently it doesn't exist in ASP.Net.  (We're using .Net 4.0 if that means anything.)

Comment: if you want to find `hyperlinkcolumn` in code behind then you can easily do it using `FindControl` in `GridViewRow`. sorry if I not understand your question well

Comment: What do you mean by _the inner resulting and values have no id..._ ??

Comment: What I mean is in the html itself, can I have an "ID" value in the <td> tags?  For purposes of automated browser testing, looking for that ID in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace (in the row-databound event) all that "inner elements", for each cell in the row, with an asp object.. for example adding a asp:label inside (with an static/or dinamic id) with the same Text (content) as the value of each cell.